# bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj returns None when object exists

Tags: python, scripting, objects

As the title says, I am trying to set a specific object as the active object. Everything I have read says that `bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj`, will do this. After setting the active object, if I call `print(bpy.context.scene.objects.active)` all that comes out is `None`. If I call `print(obj)` I get `<bpy_struct, Object("Container")>`. Also, if I call print on the active object before trying to set it, it happily spits out the current active object.

Comment: My guess is the object isn't linked to the scene, in which case how can it be the scene's  active object?  Check that `scene.objects.get("Container") is not None`  Recommend posting relevant code, eg how you set `obj` to remove the _"element of guesswork_